# Play 2.5.3 cannot use JPAApi.withTransactional on application startup

Tags: playframework-2.5

I am using Play's 2.5.3. I have been trying to write initial data to my database, but it crashes with "There is no started application" and "Try to annotate with @play.jpa.Transactional" errors. Previously, I used 2.4.6, it worked fine. I checked the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration24). But I did not find my answer.

---

I use the `AbstractModule` class to create my own `Module`. Overriding the `configure()` abstract method. In that method, I bind my static inner class as `EagerSingleton`. It injects all the required variables. In this class I would like to run code with `jpa.withTransactional()`. But still the exceptions appear when I want to make a jpa interaction.

What am I missing ?

```
public class ApplicationModule extends AbstractModule {

   @Override
   public void configure() {
       bind(ApplicationInitializer.class).asEagerSingleton();
   }

   private static class ApplicationInitializer  {

      @Inject
      public ApplicationInitializer(JPAApi jpa) {

         Logger.info("Application init...");
         jpa.withTransaction(() -> {
                //... database interactions
         });
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Can it be that you have forgotten somewhere in the database interactions a JPA.em() which should be replaced with injecting JPAApi? This was the issue for me

Comment: Do you mean that I should replace every JPA.em() to the injected JPAApi's entity manager? Thanks for your tip btw.

Comment: Yes indeed. Look into every call you make within the 
jpa.withTransaction(() -> {
                //... database interactions
         }); 
and instead of JPA.em() use the injected JPAApi as in jpaApi.em()